# Android studio new update version 4.0 says Kotlin is incompatible with this new build

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-4.0

I got the new update (4.0) of android studio and the update wizard says that **kotlin and firebase services** are incompatible with this update.

[image]

Can i use the kotlin and firebase services after the update? or is it safe to download this update considering some of my active projects use kotlin.

Comment: You have to update them for 2020 update of intellij/android studio

Comment: @AnimeshSahu  There are no updates for the Kotlin plugin.

Comment: In the screenshot there's a patch size of 247 MB, isn't it an update?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu That's the update for the android studio and not for the kotlin plugin. Am I right?

Comment: That window clearly says "IDE and Plugin Updates", what do you expect? If you want to manually update plugin (without updating ide) then goto `File` -> `Settings` -> Search: Plugin -> Update manually what you like.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Manually updating it says you have already installed the latest version of kotlin plugin.

Comment: Ah then (can't say) it might be a bug, create an issue on github or jetbrains youtrack.

Comment: It's been over two years, and the new Android Studio STILL has this warning for updating.  I *really* don't want to waste a day trying to get this thing to work--I have real stuff to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same message as you and just updated it. Kotlin and Firebase plugins are bundled. That should mean that the studio is preinstalled with them and they must be compatible. Looks fine so far.

**My new version:**
Android Studio 4.0
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 20, 2020

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved this issue.
At first, please uninstall the Android Studio of the old version on your pc or laptop.
And then, please down the Android Studio of the new version and install it on your pc or laptop.
I hope this can be helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Linux you can try the below command and then update

```
chmod a-x /PATH/TO/android-studio/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/bin/*
```